# Idiom like "Fair enough!"

Tags: vocabulary, idiom, plautus

If someone disagrees with you and the argument makes you change your opinion, you might say "Fair enough!" in English. This seems to be essentially equivalent to "Oh, good point! I agree."

Is there a similar phrase in Latin? Of course, one can use verbs like *consentio* or *assentior*, but I was hoping there would be something indicating a change of opinion — or at least something a little more colorful.

I assume something like this could be found in Plautus, but I'm not familiar with his work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as we want to convey that we've been talked into something, we may do it with *persuadeo*.

One must be careful though: the expressions *mihi persuasum est* and *persuasum habeo* usually mean "I am convinced that...", **not** "I've been convinced": see [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=D5rj4TQnbE4C&pg=PA486&lpg=PA486&dq=mihi+persuasum+est+you+convinced&source=bl&ots=6aiWH43CU0&sig=ACfU3U0dQtW02J7kIALtb-YOVtT_xS4hpA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjrgIK2qcXhAhVBDGMBHTBgBKsQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=mihi%20persuasum%20est%20you%20convinced&f=false). However, Seneca does start one of his letters to Lucilius with

> Quid non potest mihi persuaderi, cui persuasum est ut navigarem?
>
> What may I not be persuaded to do, when I have been persuaded to sail?

In order to say "You've changed my mind!" we may thus either say ***(Mihi) persuasum est!*** - and after all, the "I'm convinced" nuance is excluded by the fact that we didn't originally agree - or ***Mihi persuasisti!***: in the *Digesta Iustiniani* we have

> [...], falso mihi persuasisti, tamquam eam pecuniam servo meo aut procuratori solvisses;
>
> [...], you falsely persuaded me that you would pay that money to my slave or my procurator;

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a very good approach here. Upon reading this, I actually quite like the plain *persuasisti* which is concise and emphasizes the role of the addressee. The *mihi* can be clear enough from context.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: You're definitely right (+1) when one says that after a long enough discussion. Otherwise, though, I would personally include the _mihi_ because _tibi persuasisti_ ("You [sure] have convinced yourself [of this]") would also make sense in such cases, with an almost opposite meaning.

Comment: It seems like you misunderstand either the English or the Latin. "mihi persuāsum est" means "I'm certain, convinced that, I have good ground to belive; I've decided" - it absolutely cannot be used to admit a point in a debate. "Persuāsistī" translates straightforwardly to "you've convinced me" - which is not what "fair enough" means at all, but means "I admit that you've been right and I've been wrong - the debate is over". The latter on the contrary means "all right, I accept this point, even if I'm still not convinced about the rest", and as such is often followed by a counter-point.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian: Did you skip my first paragraph (where I illustrate the spirit of my answer, apparently well received by the OP), the next one (where I state that _persuasum est_ does usually mean "I'm convinced") and the Seneca quote (where I show an instance of _mihi persuasum est_ meaning "I've been persuaded") ? Also, the OP does state he wants to convey a change of opinion on the specific matter.

Comment: Again, the idiomatic expression "mihi persuāsum est"~"persuāsum habeō" is not used to express a change of opinion (at least I've yet to see such usage), but to state one's own prior-existing opinion or decision. It is synonymous with "crēdō, arbitror, certus sum". The Seneca quote looks to be a play on words which can be parallelled with "I'm confident" and "I'm a confidant of". The former doesn't mean that someone confided something to me.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian: As for the first part of your comment, I already said that's the most common meaning. I disagree with your interpretation of the Seneca quote, and all the translations I've seen also do not reflect it.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian Actually, I don't see a big difference between "fair enough" and "you've convinced me". I think the suggestion in this answer communicates the idea very well. I have to disagree with your analysis. // If anyone wants to discuss the matter further, I recommend asking a new question. That's always the best way to sort out things like this.

Comment: I agree that "persuāsistī" (you've convinced me) can be used to finish a debate. With "mihi persuāsum est", the difference is that between "fair enough" and "I'm certain". You can modify the latter with "now" to signal finally being swayed, but it doesn't signal agreement on its own. I agree with the interpretation of Seneca's quote in your translation - and it expresses what it normally does here, the background information for the communicative situation, it's starting point, the speaker's prior conviction. Any change of opinion has already taken place in the past.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the idea of understated or grudging respect, a good choice might be *non male dictum* (not badly said) or *non male dixisti* (you've spoken not badly), the understated counterpart of the more common *bene dictum* (well said). Both phrases are used with the connotation of "made a good point."

Varro, On Agriculture:

> Non male ... Diophanes Bithynos scribit (Diophanes of Bithynia makes a not too shabby point...)

Answer (score 2):

'Fair enough' is a phrase that implies its speaker's reluctance in giving assent. It can cover a range of situations, but it finally it's an agreement to concede a point and to move on.

I would say that the simplest equivalent is an unqualified  *habeas*.  Another possibility is *(con)cedo*.

The difficulty with this phrase, I think, stems from the fact that English, with its simple, easily-learnt grammar, needs a much greater appreciation of its peculiar idioms than is often conceded by non-native users. To turn the question back, Is that fair enough, or is more explanation required?

Comment: Tom Cotton: Yes, habeas, giving "you (may) have it", concedo, "I give way": certe, (id est) iustum.

Answer (score -1):

Try (id est) iustum; giving well-grounded/ well-deserved.

Comment: Are there any attestations of this phrase? Is it mentioned in a dictionary or something? I'm not convinced yet that it really means that. (Concerning your comment about me asking questions as well as answering them: I have asked quite a lot of questions, about 20 % of all the questions on the site. You can see the list of questions and answers in every user's profile.)

Comment: Before the edit I thought you really meant *id est istum* (with a form of the pronoun *iste*). With the added *u* it makes much more sense and I removed my downvote, but the question still stands. If you get a nice answer to [your follow-up question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/10582/79), make sure to update this answer!

Comment: Joonas llmavirta: Apologies for the spelling mistake that caused the (my) confusion. There´s an answer from Kingshorsey on the "Revisited" Q.