# How to say "in all fairness" or "to be fair" in latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom, politeness

I am very new to Latin. I was wondering how you'd say something like "in all fairness" or "to be fair" in Latin. I have been searching for the answer for hours and I couldn't find a single post about it, althought someone I know did suggest "aequitate", but I'm not sure if that really works. I know phrases like "to be fair" is rather "English", so if a more or less direct translation is awkward to use, what are some alternatives that can be used in similar contexts?

Comment: I think Cicero uses *dicam*, the first person singular present active subjunctive,(let me say, may I say), in the Philippics. I think this could work the way you want.

Comment: Related: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6803/idiom-like-fair-enough

Comment: Could you provide some more English synonyms or at least sample context to help us better understand the intent?

Answer (score 4):

What is fair is aequum, so you would say "ut aequum". For example, in the Satires, Horace writes:

```
... amicus dulcis, ut aequum est, mea compenset vitiis bona ...
```

...My sweet friend, to be fair, must weigh my virtues against my faults...